# How to register a class instance including a parameter in SimpleIOC

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, ioc-container

I need to create an instance of a ViewModel with a specific parameter passed to the ViewModel when created. At the same time this ViewModel instance should be registered in SimpleIOC

i thought this was the method for it:

```
SimpleIoc.Register<TClass> Method (Func<TClass>, String, Boolean)
```

with set to `true` for the last parameter for instant creation.
so if i understood that correctly, this method wants a reference to a method that will create my ViewModel instance.

This is called a ClassFactory as it seems.

i tried to do it myself but all i get is

```
cannot convert from <Class> to System.Func<Class>
```

so as it seems im passing always the instance of the class, and not the method that should create it.

can someone give a short example how i can get this to work

```
public class ClassFactory
{
    public ChatWindow CreateChatWindow(RosterItemX ri)
    {
        return new ChatWindow(ri);
    }
}


public class ViewModelLocator
{
.
.
.
.
    public static void CreateWindow(RosterItemX riv)
    {
        ClassFactory cf = new ClassFactory;

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ChatWindow>(cf.CreateChatWindow(ri), "key", true )
        var _messageWindow = new MessageWindow();
        _messageWindow.Show();
    }
}


class ChatMessage
{
    RosterItemX ri = new RosterItemX();
    ViewModelLocator.CreateWindow(ri);


}
```

Comment: You should give the actual code, not the method signature. That way we can see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you yourself said you are giving an instance of a `ChatWindow` to the function. However, it actually expects a function that creates a `ChatWindow`. Just convert the first parameter to a lambda with `() =>`

`SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ChatWindow>(() => cf.CreateChatWindow(ri), "key", true);`

Comment: thanks, i did know what i did wrong, but didnt know how to do that. i probably should read up on lambda.

Comment: A bit late for you perhaps, Themis, but this YouTube playlist is great for getting your head around lambdas: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdbkZkVDyKZU5ZXqp5YP1TS3irQKHZilU