# DependencyService.Get<>() not working

Tags: xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app with xamarin.forms which hase to play some sound.
For that is created an interface 'IAudioPlayer'

```
namespace ClassLibrary.AudioPlayer
{
    public interface IAudioPlayer
    {
        void PlayAudio(string filename);
    }
}
```

And in the droid project i've got the implementation like this:

```
using System;
using Android.Media;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(myApp.Droid.AudioPlayer_Android))]

namespace myApp.Droid
{
    public class AudioPlayer_Android : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, ClassLibrary.AudioPlayer.IAudioPlayer, AudioTrack.IOnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener
    {
        public void PlayAudio(string filename)
        {
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            var fd     = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(filename);

            player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
            {
                player.Start();
            };

            player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            player.Prepare();
        }

        public void OnMarkerReached(AudioTrack track)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

now when i call `DependencyService.Get<ClassLibrary.AudioPlayer.IAudioPlayer>();` it breaks and says "Method 'Get' not found in type 'Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService'.
When im Using `DependencyService.Get<>()` with another Type (Local DB implementation for example) it works fine.

Any Idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation of `IAudioPlayer` is an Android `Activity`. Dependency service will try to create an instance of it - probably not a good idea. I cannot really explain the error you get, but you should create a concrete implementation which uses one interface only:

```
public class MyAndroidPlyer : IAudioPlayer
{}
```

The Forms dependency service only has pretty basic functionality (you can check out the source [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Core/DependencyService.cs))

If you need something more sophisticated, there are alternatives, like [MvvmLight/SimpleIOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795596/how-to-use-mvvmlight-simpleioc).