# what happened when MVVMLight SimpleIoc registered multiple times?

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, simpleioc

I'd like to know when `.Register()` is performed multiple times. Based on my experiment, below `Console.WriteLine` gives same `Init` value.

So, does `.Register()` check already registered instance and *ignore* to re-register?

```
void Main()
{
    // #1
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TestClass>();
    Console.WriteLine(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<TestClass>().Init);

    // #2   
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TestClass>();
    Console.WriteLine(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<TestClass>().Init);

    // Result: #1 and #2 give identical Init value.
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Init { get; set;}
    public TestClass()
    {
        Init = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want some official documentation about this behavior?

Comment: @Evk // that would be great :) I was a questioner of this post; https://stackoverflow.com/q/13795596/361100

Comment: Well if look at source code it's clear that it behaves as you describe (registers only once), but I don't think there is some official documentation about that.

Comment: @Evk // well, i tried to find it on mvvmlight codeplex site but due to limited search capability on the site, I couldn't find it. I didn't clone yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If look at source code of `Register` method by decompiling it (in case you cannot find \ don't want to bother with actual source code), you will see (with irrelevant parts skipped):

```
public void Register<TClass>(bool createInstanceImmediately) where TClass : class
{
  Type index = typeof (TClass);
  // skipped irrelevant parts
  if (this._factories.ContainsKey(index) && this._factories[index].ContainsKey(this._defaultKey))
  {
     if (!this._constructorInfos.ContainsKey(index))
       throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Class {0} is already registered.", (object) index));
  } else {
      if (!this._interfaceToClassMap.ContainsKey(index))
        this._interfaceToClassMap.Add(index, (Type) null);
      this._constructorInfos.Add(index, this.GetConstructorInfo(index));
      Func<TClass> factory = new Func<TClass>(this.MakeInstance<TClass>);
      this.DoRegister<TClass>(index, factory, this._defaultKey);
      if (!createInstanceImmediately)
        return;
      this.GetInstance<TClass>();
    }
  }
}
```

So, if there is already registered factory in `_factories` dictionary - it checks if there is constructor info registered for this type and if NOT - throws exception about already registered class. I suppose this is a typo and check should be reversed - if there IS already registered constructor (which you register in else block) - there should be exception about already registered class. But as it is implemented now - it just does nothing when you try to register second time.